# Como puedo guardar una variable de Javascript en php

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer un formulario que calcule la calidad de implementación de ciertos materiales de matemáticas. El problema es que no se como guardar el valor de variable que contiene el resultado de la implementacion,en php, y por ende en MySQL

Javascript

```
$(function(){
  $("input[type=radio]").add("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function(){
    calcular();
  })

});

function calcular(){
  $radios = $("input[type=radio]:checked");
  $checkboxs = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
  var coste_total = 0;
  $checkboxs.each(function(){
    coste_total = coste_total + parseInt($(this).val());
  })
  $radios.each(function(){
    coste_total = coste_total + parseInt($(this).val());
  })
  $(".resultado").html(coste_total)
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "");

if(!$conexion){
echo "Conexión no exitosa";
} else {

$base= mysqli_select_db($conexion, "datos1");
    if(!$base){
        echo "No se pudo conectar a la base de datos";
    }
}
//LLAMAMOS LAS VARIBALES
$Teachers_Name="";
$Teachers_Name= isset($_POST['Teachers_Name']) ? $_POST['Teachers_Name']:'';
$Teachers_Name= empty($_POST['Teachers_Name']) ? $_POST['Teachers_Name']:'';
$Teachers_Name= $_POST['Teachers_Name'] ?? '';
$School_Name="";
$School_Name= isset($_POST['School_Name']) ? $_POST['School_Name']:'';
$School_Name= empty($_POST['School_Name']) ? $_POST['School_Name']:'';
$School_Name= $_POST['School_Name'] ?? '';
$Implementation_Quality= $_POST['coste_total'];
//Guarda las variables


$sql= "INSERT INTO datos_1 (Teachers_Name, School_Name, 
                            Implementation_Quality) VALUES(?, 
                            ?,'Implementation_Quality')";

$sth = mysqli_prepare($conexion,$sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sth,'sss', $Teachers_Name, $School_Name, 
$Implementation_Quality);
 $ejecutar = mysqli_stmt_execute($sth);

if(!$ejecutar){
 echo "Hubo algun error";
} else {
    echo "Datos guardados correctamente<br><a href='index.html'>Volver</a>";
}

?>
```

HTML

```
 <p  class="resultado" style="background:#0774D9" id="coste_total" name="coste_total" value="coste_total" >Implementation Quality</p>
               <input type="submit" value="send">
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar AJAX desde tu código JavaScript y ejecutar el script en PHP pasándole la información que necesita.

con jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "tuscriptphp.php",
   type: "POST" // o GET, o PUT, PATCH, etc...
   data: {
      Teachers_Name: Teachers_Name_valor
      School_Name: School_Name_valor
      coste_total: coste_total_valor
      /* Tus otras variabels... */
   },
   success: function(response) {
      /*
         Lo que quieras que se ejecute si todo estuvo bien en la ejecución PHP
      */
   }
});
```

Comment: Entonces, cambio la manera de llamar las variables por esa?

Comment: @Marinowsky Te estas confundiendo con los lenguajes de programación, en javascript las varables no necesitan llevar `$` como en `$radios`, en php si lo necesita y en javascript no. Eso provoca que te estés confundiendo. Lo que hace que en javascript uses `$` es la biblioteca de jquery, y debes de tener cuidado de confundir con php. No debes cambiar la manera de llamar variables. El código que te pusieron es como invocar código php desde javascript PASANDO PARAMETROS. El paso de parámetros es lo que hace que puedes enviar valores de javascript a php, y eso es lo que preguntaste.